# "Школа имени генерал-майора". Прописная буква?

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная, названия

Школа имени Генерал-майора? Или: Школа имени генерал-майора?

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: **школа имени генерал-майора...**

Образцы названий школы (полного и сокращенного):

1) Муниципальное бюджетное общеобразовательное учреждение Дубровская №1 средняя общеобразовательная школа имени генерал-майора Никитина Ивана Семеновича;

2)  МБОУ Дубровская №1 СОШ им. генерал-майора Никитина;

3) школа им. генерал-майора Никитина.

**С прописной буквы пишутся:**

- первое слово (в полном названии с указанием статуса школы  это два "начальных" слова);
- условное название (Дубровская);
- входящие имена собственные (Никитина).

**Остальные слова пишутся со строчной буквы.**